# Unused birth certificate inquiry

Tags: england-and-wales, citizenship

I was born in the UK in the 60s and I have a certificate of birth and a certified copy of an entry of birth both from the sub district of Sefton Park of Liverpool South district in the County Borough of Liverpool but my name does not appear in any of the UK archives and I currently live in a different country and have never personally used the birth certificate. Does this mean that I am not a registered citizen of the UK? Or is my birth certificate invalid? Why does my name not appear in my of the archive records?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com) answers a lot of questions like this.

Comment: @Spencer: Perfect. I am confident we will find the correct home for it and migrate it for *Nimi*. It's a good and well-written question, just not a good fit for History.

Comment: If the certificate exists, and there is "_a certified copy of an entry of birth_", then those records clearly exist in the archives both at Liverpool and centrally at the General Register Office (GRO). The question of 'citizenship' is a more complex one, and probably not one that we can answer here on History:SE. I have pinged the mods at Law:SE to ask whether they think this is a suitable question for their site.

Comment: I think we need more information. Was one or both of your parents UK citizens or residents? If not citizens, what was their visa status?

Comment: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com is probably better still.  But it'd help if you can be more specific about "any of the UK archives" - exactly which archives are you talking about, and how did you determine that your name does not appear in them?

Comment: @mkennedy it doesn't matter. Before the nationality act of 1981 took effect at the beginning of 1983, the only people born in the UK who did not become citizens of the UK and colonies were children of diplomats and enemy aliens, and the latter circumstance applies only to the channel islands during the second world war.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a certified copy of the register of births, then as the comments point out, by definition your birth was registered in the UK and a record of this should exist in the General Register Office (GRO) and local registry office archives. As records are not removed from the registry, then it should still be there.

I am not sure where you have been searching "the UK archives" but you can find information on searching the GRO records [here](https://www.gov.uk/general-register-office). If you cannot find yourself in the index but you are in possession of a birth certificate, then the index is probably at fault. It is possible that the original handwritten index was entered into the system incorrectly - you may want to try different spellings?

(You wouldn't expect someone's name to appear in eg the National Archives records, so don't worry if you're not showing up there.)

*Citizenship* is a very different question - it is probable that you are entitled to UK citizenship, if you were born there in the 1960s, but I wouldn't want to say either way for sure. See the notes in comments.

[edited down to remove my confusion - thanks @phoog]

Comment: In the 1960s, birth in the UK *did* automatically confer British nationality. Citizenship of the UK and colonies (CUKC) was the only citizenship of the UK that existed at the time. On 1 January 1983, the Nationality Act of 1981 granted British citizenship to every CUKC who had right of abode in the UK, which includes all CUKCs who were born in the UK.  Nimi is certainly a British citizen unless born to parents who were diplomats from another country posted to the UK.

Comment: @phoog good point, thanks - I had somehow forgotten the change to the modern approach was as late as then. So if I've got this right, the 1981 Act gave citizenship to anyone with right of abode (s. 11); the 1971 Act gave RoA to any existing CUKC born in the UK (s. 2(1)a); and we can assume someone born in the UK in the 60s absent unusual conditions was CUKC?

Comment: @phoog this had slipped my mind completely, but have come back & corrected the error